# unable to load hadoop fs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have installed hadoop on Ubuntu 4.4.3.I have followed all steps written in [here](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster).When I ran a command hadoop fs -ls . I got following output.

```
hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ hadoop fs -ls /
Found 26 items
drwx------   - root   root        16384 2010-04-04 05:08 /lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   - root   root         4096 2012-08-25 09:12 /bin
drwxr-xr-x   - root   root         4096 2009-10-28 13:55 /srv
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root      7986235 2012-08-25 09:29 /initrd.img
dr-xr-xr-x   - root   root            0 2013-09-01 15:57 /proc
drwx------   - root   root         4096 2013-09-01 11:04 /root
drwxrwxrwx   - root   root         4096 2012-08-26 05:12 /opt
drwxr-xr-x   - root   root         4096 2010-04-04 05:29 /mnt
drwxr-xr-x   - root   root         4096 2009-10-28 13:55 /usr
drwxr-xr-x   - root   root         4096 2010-04-04 05:09 /cdrom
drwxr-xr-x   - root   root            0 2013-09-01 15:57 /sys
drwxr-xr-x   - hduser hadoop       4096 2013-08-25 03:47 /app
drwxr-xr-x   - root   root         4096 2010-11-24 10:50 /var
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root      4050496 2012-07-25 09:53 /vmlinuz
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root      3890400 2009-10-16 11:03 /vmlinuz.old
drwxr-xr-x   - root   root         4096 2010-11-27 08:37 /.cache
drwxr-xr-x   - root   root         4096 2013-09-01 22:26 /media
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root      7233695 2012-08-25 08:53 /initrd.img.old
drwxr-xr-x   - root   root        12288 2013-09-01 22:46 /etc
drwxr-xr-x   - root   root         4096 2013-08-25 03:30 /home
drwxr-xr-x   - root   root         3980 2013-09-01 15:57 /dev
drwxr-xr-x   - root   root        12288 2012-08-25 22:07 /lib
drwxrwxrwt   - root   root         4096 2013-09-01 23:53 /tmp
drwxr-xr-x   - root   root         4096 2012-08-25 09:29 /boot
drwxr-xr-x   - root   root         4096 2009-10-19 16:05 /selinux
drwxr-xr-x   - root   root         4096 2012-08-25 09:04 /sbin
```

When I run same command in our office lab ,  I didnt get this op.
Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong ?

Comment: Can you explain what's the office lab?

Comment: I feel he means his office laboratory where he works..

Comment: @Prafull Tilwankar : hadoop version?

Comment: @Tariq, version is Hadoop 0.20.2-cdh3u6

Answer (score 0):

Try **bin/hadoop fs -ls /**. Scripts should be present inside bin folder. Have you followed the link, you have shown, properly?I don't find sbin anywhere in this. Could you please point me to it, if I am wrong.

Comment: yes I have followed everything as per link. I have only skipped IP6 section. I have added hadoop/bin folder to $PATH . so directly using hadoop instead of bin/hadoop.sbin folder is there.

Comment: even with above command bin/hadoop fs -ls / , getting same o/p.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you did not configure your core-site.xml correctly with the attribute "fs.default.name". When you don't configure it or you incorrectly configure it, the filesystem will be the default one which is your local file system. So rightly it is listing the root of your local file system.

Please check your core-site.xml carefully and also you need to start the DFS before using the HDFS.

Comment: I have configured correctly fs.default.name in core-site.xml.here is content  `hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ hdfs getconf -confKey fs.defaultFS
hdfs://localhost:54310
hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ hdfs getconf -confKey hadoop.tmp.dir
/app/hadoop/tmp
`
I have started dfs as well.

Comment: It is taking the local FS as the default filesyste. Can you copy you core-site.xml here

Comment: `<configuration>
<property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
  <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
  <description>The name of the default file system. ... </description>
</property>
</configuration>`

Comment: fs.default.name is deprecated , I am using fs.defaultFS.

Comment: can you try using fs.default.name instead of fs.defaultFS. It is deprecated but let us try. It still works.

Comment: Did you also check if your daemons are running? like NameNode, DataNode, SNN?

Comment: Also check if the XML header information is there at the begining of your core-site.xml file, like <?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

Comment: Getting list of local file system even after changing to fs.defaultFS.After changing, i have run 3 commands 1)>>hadoop namenode -format 2)>>./start-dfs.sh 3)>>./start-yarn.sh

Comment: Looks like you are using CDH? which version are you using?

Comment: Yes..CDH is mentioned in the comment above. I don't think **fs.default.name** should cause any harm, since user is on CDH3. But i'm wondering why do you want to use CDH3. I mean Cloudera will not support or provide patches for any of the Cloudera Manager version 3 and CDH3 releases. They have reached EOM as of June 20th, 2013.

Comment: When i tried this `hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost:54310/
` , i got this error `ls: Server IPC version 8 cannot communicate with client version 4`